# Finding elements of a given type in an array in C#

Tags: c#, types

I have a Fleet class that contains an array of (base class) Vehicles.  The vehicles in the array are subclasses of Vehicles: Plains, Trains and Automobiles.  The array is private, but the Fleet class must offer a method to get at the vehicles of a given type.

Something like:

```
class Fleet
{
    private Vehicle[] _vehicles;

    // returns the vehicles of the specified subclass
    public ???? Get(????)
    {
        return ????
    }
}

Fleet fleet = new Fleet("fleet.def");

Trains[] trains = fleet.Get(Trains);   // looks clean but isn't possible
Plains[] plains = fleet.Get<Plains>(); // looks okay but don't know
                                       //   how to implement
```

(I'm using arrays, but really any collection type that can be iterated is fine.)

Now, as you can see, I have absolutely no idea how to implement this.  I'm looking for an elegant solution for the Get method, efficiency is not really an issue.  Please also name the key techniques involved in the solution, so I can look them up in my C# books...

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your Fleet.Get() will look like

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
{
  return _vehicles.OfType<T>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dh!  Looks very clean.  Now I can use "foreach (Plain plain in fleet.Get<Plain>()) { }.  I guess that I can also use .ToList() and .ToArray() to store the result in a variable?

What is this technique with the angle brackets called (yes, I am a n00b and not ashamed of it)?

Comment: That's called generics. The idea is to substitute a concrete type for reusability (for example when you have similar operations over different types). You can find out more in Introduction to Generics at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a generic name for such a specific thing :-)  Thanks again, I have some reading to do...

Answer (score 1):

Make it a `List<>` and use `FindAll(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Train))` to get all Train objects from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public T[] Get<T>() where T : Vehicle
 {
     List<Vehicle> lstVehicles = new List<Vehicle>(_vehicles);
     return lstVehicles.FindAll(delegate(Vehicle vehicle){
         return vehicle.GetType() == typeof(T);
     }).ToArray();
 }
```